# Ashkenazim and Kitniyot on Erev Pesach

Tags: passover, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, chametz-leaven, ashkenazi

The following hypothetical case was raised in class today:

An American (ashkenazic) Jew is visiting Israel. On Erev Pesach, he has a hankering for sushi (the word hankering was not used in class -- this is my emendation). So he goes to a Sephardic, K for P restaurant. Can he order and eat sushi with rice?

This developed from a broader question -- can a Jew eat someone else's chameitz on erev pesach (so there is no issue of owning it) even if it means accepting any punishment for theft?

Comment: What was the answer in class?

Comment: the students raised the hypothetical -- I had no answer so I promised I'd post it. They'll ask anything to avoid studying literature.

Comment: Eating any chametz on Erev Pesach after Chatzot is for sure a Biblical prohibition! Kitniyot is only a minhag and there may be what to talk about, but I think the minhag is not to eat it. But certainly no chametz.

Comment: the zmanim for this friday indicate a 2 hour window between last time to eat and chatzot and a 1 hour window after bi'ur and chatzot

Comment: @Dan That's because there is a 2 hour period prior to Chatzot where eating chametz is rabinnically prohibited and a 1 hour window prior to chatzot where owning chametz is rabinnically prohibited. But starting from chatzot the prohibition is biblical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Chok Yaakov, cited by [Shevet Halevi (OC 31)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1413&st=&pgnum=39), the custom to refrain from eating *kitniyot* begins on Erev Pesach, just the same as the prohibition of eating *chametz*.