# Can I eat Kitniot?

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ashkenazim and Kitniyot on Erev Pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15566/ashkenazim-and-kitniyot-on-erev-pesach)

My minhag (Ashkanazi), prohibits the consumption of kitniyos on Pesach.

Does that mean that I can eat kitniyos erev Pesach?